# Low disk storage Space

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory

I have not added applications to my phone.  I have actually been deleting applications from my phone because it will tell me I have low disk storage space.  Sometimes it goes away, but will come back at another time when I still have not added any applications from the market.  I'm not sure how to keep it from telling me this...

Comment: I have the same problem. It's getting ridiculous: I have to re-install Android every month.

Answer (score 4):

Cache from installed apps also resides on the phone's internal memory, and if not cleared in a while can grow large enough to fill it up.  Go to `Menu -> Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> Menu -> Sort by size`.  Then tap on the largest apps and tap on the `Clear Cache` button.  GMail, Browser and Maps are known space hogs.

You can try various apps that clear cache with one click.  For example, [aCCleaner](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.acc.free) or [CacheMate](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.aac.cachemate.demo).  Keep in mind that some of these apps require root.