# SD card won't format on my Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, internal-storage, formatting

My Samsung Galaxy S3 tells me that I have used up all of my memory. So, I bought a brand-new 32GB SD card, and placed it in the phone. I went to storage settings and followed the instructions to format the SD card. Then, it tells me it's updating memory and my total space available is 32GB remaining.

However, nothing is happening. It still says I have ran out of memory. I have turned off the phone and turned it back on several times. I have also restarted phone. I have formatted SD card many times, but nothing is happening.

This is frustrating, because I deleted so many apps because it's not letting me download or open anything because it's full.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If your device talks about "low memory", it is not evaluating the sd card -- but rather means *internal memory*. So it doesn't help to buy a bigger sd card: what you have to do is to free up internal storage.

This is an issue coming up here frequently -- so for details please look at the solutions already present:

- [Low disk storage Space](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9398/16575)
- [More internal memory or less memory + SD card](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32115/16575)
- [My internal storage capacity is running low, what can I do?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29416/16575)
- [Message Memory Full, Incoming message rejected](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35958/16575)

There are many more -- just follow the [internal-storage](/questions/tagged/internal-storage) tag and watch out...